# FFMPEG: encode x265, container mpeg2 ts, stream-STARTCODE MISSING

Tags: ffmpeg, udp, video-streaming, mpeg2-ts, hevc

I am trying to encode a video with FFMPEG x265, put it into MPEG2 TS and then stream it over UDP. Then receive on another PC and save it. Perform PSNR.

The encoding works fine, but when I try to stream I get the error:

> **[mpegts @ 00000000050b0520] HEVC bitstream error, startcode missing, size 1436 data 00000100**

- Step 1- Encoding:

> ffmpeg -re -i test.ts -r 25 -b:v 2500k -preset medium -c:v libx265 -x265-params crf=27 -y -f mpegts test1.ts

No error, everything fine.

- Step 2- Streaming:

Start code missing.

`ffmpeg -re -i test1.ts -c copy -f mpegts udp://172.18.60.47:1234
ffmpeg version N-68441-g4fa42e0 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Dec 14 2014 22:13:03 with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnut
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --e
modplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsc
r --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-
 --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-decklink --enable-zl
  libavutil      54. 15.100 / 54. 15.100
  libavcodec     56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavformat    56. 15.105 / 56. 15.105
  libavdevice    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
  libavfilter     5.  3.101 /  5.  3.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mpegts, from 'test1.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:10.12, start: 1.480000, bitrate: 456 kb/s
  Program 1
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: hevc (Main) ([36][0][0][0] / 0x0024), yuv420p(tv), 1280x720, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
Output #0, mpegts, to 'udp://172.18.60.47:1234':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.15.105
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc ([36][0][0][0] / 0x0024), yuv420p, 1280x720, q=2-31, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
**[mpegts @ 0000000004ed7320] HEVC bitstream error, startcode missing, size 2462 data 00000102**
[mpegts @ 0000000004ed7320] HEVC bitstream error, startcode missing, size 302 data 00000102
[mpegts @ 0000000004ed7320] HEVC bitstream error, startcode missing, size 134 data 00000100
[mpegts @ 0000000004ed7320] HEVC bitstream error, startcode missing, size 149 data 00000100
[mpegts @ 0000000004ed7320] HEVC bitstream error, startcode missing, size 5107 data 00000102
[mpegts @ 0000000004ed7320] HEVC bitstream error, startcode missing, size 1331 data 00000102
[mpegts @ 0000000004ed7320] HEVC bitstream error, startcode missing, size 341 data 00000100
frame=    8 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=      37kB time=00:00:00.24 bitrate=1278.4kbits/s
video:34kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 9.718209%
Received signal 2: terminating.`

When I do the steps above with x264 everything works fine. I can stream the video and I can receive it on the other side. Any idea what is wrong? Is this a BUG?

Commands for x264:

> ffmpeg  -re -i test.ts -r 25 -b:v 2500k -preset medium -c:v libx264 -x264-params crf=27  -y  -f mpegts test1.ts
>
> ffmpeg -re -i test1.ts -c copy -f mpegts udp://172.18.60.47:1234

Thanks for the help!!

BR,
Rudi

Comment: I also reported a ticket on FFMPEG: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4194#comment:2

Comment: Well, actually you can stream it and play it with FFplayt. Although there is some error with the implementation of FFmpeg MPEG2-TS. When there is packet loss in the network the decoders drops video frames. x264 and x265. No solution for this problem.